# Form onSubmit security

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm busy with an assignment where i have to make a website with a form where the user should at least order 1 product before he can continue. I've got it that far, it's all working fine using this piece of javascript code:

```
function validateForm()
    {
        var allEmpty = (document.forms['orderform'].PizzaMargherita.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].PizzaFungi.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].PizzaHawai.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].PizzaQuattroStagioni.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].PizzaCalzone.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].BroodjeShoarma.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].BroodjeDoner.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].DurumDoner.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].KnoflookSaus.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].WhiskeySaus.value == "" &&
                        document.forms['orderform'].SambalSaus.value == "");

        if(allEmpty)
        {
            document.forms[0].submit.disabled=true;
        }
        else {  
            document.forms[0].submit.disabled=false;
        }
    }
```

Except there should be some kind of security from using f12 (show source code) and remove `min="1"` on the input field for example.

```
<tr>
    <td>Pizza Margherita</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="countMargherita" class="formnumbers" name="PizzaMargherita" onChange="validateForm(this);changeTotalFromCount(this);" min="1" max="99" data-unitprice="7"/></td>
    <td><span id="totalMargherita"></span></td>
    <td>&#8364; 7.00</td>
</tr>
```

I don't really know how i should do this, someone told me i should use javascript instead but as far as i know you can just remove the `onChange="validateForm(this);` so that isn't very safe either. I'm looking for a way that if the user would order for example order -2 products it would stop the form from submitting. Or just throw in an error.

Something that won't be removable or being found by using f12, i don't know if i'm correct with saying this but as far as i know you cant find PHP code using the view source code.

I'm nowhere near experienced in PHP or JS so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's true, you can't show PHP code on the client side as it's interpreted on server and only client-side code is sent to browser. That is, if you validate your form with PHP it will solve your problem. Search for "PHP Form Validation" :)

Comment: Do server site validation also with that

Comment: @AshrafSamhouri But as you can see i have some JS code in my input field, just like the price for each item as `data-unpitprice`how should i make it so those can't be deleted using F12 or something

Answer (score 1):

Client side validation is only a convenience for the user. There is no way you can definitely prevent a malicious client from sending wacky values.

The best thing to do is validate on the server to ensure that all values are reasonable and redirect back to the page with errors if appropriate.

Comment: common server-side validations include min/max values or allowed characters of form field values, no line breaks on emails or any other field values that will be used in email headers, sanitizing your data before inserting into your db tables, make sure your form is submitted from your own pages/server and many many more you can find by searching the web.

Answer (score 0):

Try document.document.getElementById() ::

```
function validateForm()
{
    var allEmpty = (document.getElementById("PizzaMargherita").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("PizzaFungi").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("PizzaHawai").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("PizzaQuattroStagioni").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("PizzaCalzone").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("BroodjeShoarma").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("BroodjeDoner").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("DurumDoner").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("KnoflookSaus").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("WhiskeySaus").value == "" &&
                    document.getElementById("SambalSaus").value == "");

    if(allEmpty)
    {
        document.forms[0].submit.disabled=true;
    }
    else {  
        document.forms[0].submit.disabled=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should i replace forms with getElementById? (newbie in JS)